# squid - ssl bump

Tags: proxy, ssl, squid

I have squid configured to bump SSL connections; however, when I configure my browser to use squid as a proxy, it doesn't actually do any SSL bumping.  When I check the certificate, I can see it is still using the original and not one that I'm expecting to see.

I followed the configuration from here:
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump

I also see that SSL Bump is enabled on port 3128 and my transparent proxy is on 3129.  Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

There is a more detailed explanation about settings you need [DynamicSSL](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DynamicSslCert)

For example

```
always_direct allow all
ssl_bump allow all
# the following two options are unsafe and not always necessary:
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
```

and the cert caching preparation.

Comment: The only one it appears I am missing is ssl_bump allow all - the others shouldn't be there for reference as

Comment: since you didn't say what version you use, the docs could be deprecated. Some of the settings are now called `client-first`, `server-first`. Please take look at  your `squid.conf.documented`.

Comment: Okay, I am using client-first and it didn't appear to work.  It also didn't work with allow all.  I'll take a look again this evening at squid.conf.documented to see which one it should be.